# jQuery enlarge image map on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image over which I created hotspots for hyperlinks using image map. Now I need to enlarge/zoom over the images on mouse over. I have this so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.mapping').mouseover(function() {

 $(this).animate({
    width: "110%",
    height: "50%"
  }, 'slow');

});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<map id="ImgMap0" name="ImgMap0">
 <area alt="" coords="4, 14, 67, 34" id="a" class="mapping" 
 href="#" shape="rect" />
<area alt="" coords="5, 55, 70, 74" id="b" class="mapping" 
href="# shape="rect" />
....
<img alt="" class="auto-style1" height="529" src="Tools.jpg" 
width="800" usemap="#ImgMap0" /></p>

</p></body>
```

But the animate () is not working. Alert is being called so I know mouseover() is working. Any ideas for enlarging the area in image map?

JS Fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/z2Lkf8p0/

Comment: I'm assuming you've added `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` in `<head>` section.

Comment: Yes. I didn't paste it here. Alert is called so Jquery is working

Comment: Could you create a JSfiddle? Then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I'd updated my answer, i think that will work for you.

Comment: Can you check all the answers ?

Comment: I cannot have absolute divs because I know only coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot enlarge image's map in any way.

---

You can do this with another way. I'd created a fiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/141bkx84/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
    <div class="map1 map"></div>
    <div class="map2 map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {

    position: relative;
    width: 600px;

}

.container img {

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

}

.map {

    position: absolute;
    background: #F0F;
    z-index: 2;

}

.map1 {

    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}

.map2 {

    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}
```

JS

```
$(".map").on("mouseenter", function () {

    $(this).animate({

        width: "200px",
        height: "200px"

    });

});
```

Area to CSS convert

If all areas types are rectangle its easy. n1,n2,n3,n4

n1: y beginning
n2: x beginning
n3: y ending
n4: x ending

You can convert it.

```
left:   n2;
top:    n1;
width:  n3 - n1;
height: n4 - n2;
```

Comment: Can I replace with zoomed in image on mouse over then?

Comment: I prefer changing your maps with transparent absolute divs. With this way you can do whatever you want. I will create fiddle for you.

Comment: I know only the coordinates of the hotspot. How can I convert it to absolute divs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.mapping').hover(function() {
       alert('Mouse Hovered');
       //some statements   
 });

});
</script>
```

Good Luck.. ['}

Comment: No relation with question. Question is enlarging image map.

Comment: I want to enlarge the image map.